# How can i move a bone in edit mode without it affecting the Weight paint?

Tags: rigging, armature, edit-mode, bones, transforms

[image]I got this rig, where I have all the weight paint done. It's good, but the bone position just isn't right. Is there a way I can move these bones in edit mode without it affecting the mesh?

[image]

Comment: Hello, if you move the bones in Edit mode it won't affect the mesh

Comment: It did tho; i don't know why.

Comment: it may have to do with constraints, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/0xay9JB7. Here. Btw i'm using GooEngine

Comment: Could you please tell what is the bone that you are trying to move?

Comment: The mouth bones, LIP.T.L

Comment: It looks like DEF-lip.T.L points towards lip.T.L.001 because of a Damped Track and a Stretch To constraint, so if you rmove lip.T.L.001 in Edit mode you also need to reajust these bones so that they stick to lip.T.L.001, more generally if you are not familiar with Rigify you should not use it because it's a bit complicated imho

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!

Comment: I've given an answer, I hope it's clearer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like *DEF-lip.T.L*, which is a defomring bone, points towards *lip.T.L.001* because of a *Damped Track* and a *Stretch To* constraint with *lip.T.L.001* as *Target*:

[image]

So if you remove *lip.T.L.001* in *Edit* mode you also need to reajust *DEF-lip.T.L* so that it sticks back to *lip.T.L.001* and doesn't jumpe once you switch to *Pose* mode:

[image]

Note that these two bones are in the *Face (Primary)* and in the *DEF* layers:

[image]